Hot to create a common method to handle exception in Java?
I'm working in a Spring Boot project and I want to create a common method to handle exception because I have the same code in 3 methods.
For example:
public SomeObj1 method1() {
    try {
        ....
        return ...;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        log.error(....);
        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
            case NOT_FOUND:
                throw new CustomNotFoundException(e);
            case BAD_REQUEST:
                throw new CustomBadRequestException(e);
            default:
                throw new CustomInternalServerException(e);
    }
}

public SomeObj2 method1() {
    try {
        ....
        return ...;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        log.error(....);
        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
            case NOT_FOUND:
                throw new CustomNotFoundException(e);
            case BAD_REQUEST:
                throw new CustomBadRequestException(e);
            default:
                throw new CustomInternalServerException(e);
    }
}

public SomeObj3 method1() {
    try {
        ....
        return ...;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        log.error(....);
        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
            case NOT_FOUND:
                throw new CustomNotFoundException(e);
            case BAD_REQUEST:
                throw new CustomBadRequestException(e);
            default:
                throw new CustomInternalServerException(e);
    }
}

And I try to create a method to handle that exception like this:
private void handlingExc(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            log.error(....);
            switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                case NOT_FOUND:
                    throw new CustomNotFoundException(e);
                case BAD_REQUEST:
                    throw new CustomBadRequestException(e);
                default:
                    throw new CustomInternalServerException(e);
        }
}

but if I try to call that method from the catch block I get missing return statement
public SomeObj1 method1() {
    try {
        ....
        return ...;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        handlingExc(e);
    }
}

Can somebody explain how to create a method to handle that exc and call it from catch block of all 3 methods? Thank you!

You should write an exception handler: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-exceptionhandler.html

Note you might benefit from bubbling those exceptions up (e.g. method1() throws CustomNotFoundException, ... {), so that callers of your methods can handle the errors instead. This also means the methods with similar exceptions can be called together within the same single try/catch block. Another alternative is a functional interface that allows for exceptions to be thrown, so you can write lambdas that allow for the errors and then catch them/handle them internal to your class.

If handlingExc never completes normally, you may rewrite it to always return an exception. Then, adapt the caller to use throw handlingExc(e);
